# How to view first picture in a file using php?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to figure out how to display the first image in an album that the user uploads.  I have a website that lets users upload images to albums, Now I want to display the first picture in the album as the album cover, right now when the user clicks on the albums page all that shows is the album info like name, description, etc. and I used the album name as the link to view the images in the album, what I want is the first image in the album to be displayed as link to that album. I have alot of stuff going on with this but I will try and provide everything so you can understand easier.  Here is my albums page code:

```
$albums = get_albums();

if(empty($albums)){
echo 'No Albums';
}else{

foreach($albums as $album){
    echo '<p><a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'] ,'">', $album['name'],'</a>(', $album['count'], ' images) <br />
    ', $album['description'], '...<br />
    <a href="edit_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'] , '">Edit</a> / <a href="delete_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'] , '">Delete</a>
    </p>';
}
}
```

Here is the function from my functions php file that I include in this file:

```
function get_albums(){
$albums = array();

$albums_query = mysql_query("
SELECT `albums`.`album_id`, `albums`.`timestamp`, `albums`.`name`, LEFT(`albums`.`description`, 50) as `description`, COUNT(`images`.`image_id`) as `image_count`
FROM `albums`
LEFT JOIN `images`
ON `albums`.`album_id` = `images`.`album_id`
WHERE `albums`.`user_id` = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "
GROUP BY `albums`.`album_id`
");

while($albums_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($albums_query)){
    $albums[] = array(
        'id'            => $albums_row['album_id'],
        'timestamp'     => $albums_row['timestamp'],
        'name'          => $albums_row['name'],
        'description'   => $albums_row['description'],
        'count'         => $albums_row['image_count']
    );
}

return $albums;

}
```

Now I am a little lost and confused on what route to take to change the link to open the albums from the album name to the first image in the album.  If the albums do not have any pics in them I plan on using a simple if statement to show a generic empty folder image.  My database using two table to upload images, the first is the albums table and the second is the images table.  I also have a timestamp field that inserts the image upload timestamp, so can i return the images from that album and the image with the lowest timestamp so to return the first image uploaded to the album? Is there a SELECT statement to return this? Also I did create a folder that stores these images in the corresponding albums, can i return the first image in that album? What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Here is how I get the images path:

```
function get_images($album_id){
$album_id = (int)$album_id;

$images = array();

$image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_id`, `album_id`, `timestamp`, `ext` FROM `images` WHERE `album_id` = $album_id AND `user_id` = ". $_SESSION['user_id']);
while($images_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_query)){
    $images[] = array(
        'id'            => $images_row['image_id'],
        'album'         => $images_row['album_id'],
        'timestamp'     => $images_row['timestamp'],
        'ext'           => $images_row['ext']
    );
}
return $images;
}
```

Here is my view_album.php file:

```
if(!isset($_GET['album_id']) || empty($_GET['album_id']) || album_check($_GET['album_id']) === false){
header('Location: albums.php');
exit();
}

$album_id = $_GET['album_id'];
$album_data = album_data($album_id, 'name');

echo '<h1 class="logo2">', $album_data['name'], '</h1>';
include 'includes/menu_album.php';

$images = get_images($album_id);

if(empty($images)){
echo 'No images.';
}else{
foreach($images as $image){
    echo '<a href="uploads/', $image['album'], '/', $image['id'], '.',     $image['ext'], '"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $image['album'], '/', $image['id'], '.', $image['ext'], '" title="Uploaded ', date('D M Y', $image['timestamp']), '"></a> [<a       href="delete_image.php?image_id=', $image['id'], '">x</a>] ';
}
}
```

Comment: Just a usability comment really, users being seemingly stuck with the very first image they uploaded as being the cover.  Wouldn't you want to let the user pick which is the album cover?  It'd just an extra binary field in the table `cover`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually pretty close to getting the first image with your existing query. All you need to do as add the image name or path to the `SELECT` and the image timestamp to an `ORDER BY` to make sure you get the earliest one:

```php
   $albums_query = mysql_query("
        SELECT 
          `albums`.`album_id`, 
          `albums`.`timestamp`, 
          `albums`.`name`, 
          LEFT(`albums`.`description`, 50) as `description`, 
          COUNT(`images`.`image_id`) as `image_count`, 
          CONCAT(`images`.`image_id`, '.', `images`.`ext`) AS `first_image`
        FROM `albums`
        LEFT JOIN `images`
        ON `albums`.`album_id` = `images`.`album_id`
        WHERE `albums`.`user_id` = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "
        GROUP BY `albums`.`album_id`
        ORDER BY `albums`.`timestamp` ASC, `images`.`timestamp` ASC
    ");

    if (!$albums_query) {
      die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    while($albums_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($albums_query)){
        $albums[] = array(
            'id'            => $albums_row['album_id'],
            'timestamp'     => $albums_row['timestamp'],
            'name'          => $albums_row['name'],
            'description'   => $albums_row['description'],
            'count'         => $albums_row['image_count'],
            'image'         => $albums_row['first_image']
        );
    }
```

You can then update your output to include the image:

```
foreach($albums as $album){
    if (empty($album['image'])) {
        $album['image'] = 'default.jpg';
    }
    echo '<p>
      <a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'] ,'">
        <img src="uploads/thumbs/', $album['id'] ,'/', $album['image'] ,'" />', $album['name'],'
      </a>(', $album['count'], ' images) <br />
      ', $album['description'], '...<br />
      <a href="edit_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'] , '">Edit</a> / <a href="delete_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'] , '">Delete</a>
    </p>';
}
```

Comment: Im sorry im confused I see the logic there but I do not have a field image in my table under the $albums array you added a field of image, not sure do you want me to add that field to the table?  I don't see how that works, sorry Im sure Im missing something. It says there are no albums also even after I add one to it, my code before worked just fine I just wanted to add the first image as the link. i get this error now:                             Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lr\func\album.func.php on line 36
No Albums

Comment: Hi Aaron,
The image field should be the image location in your images table, which in your SQL is `LEFT JOINED` to the albums table. I don't know what fields are in your `images` table, so I guessed `filename`. You'll need to adapt the code to work with your actual tables.

You are getting an error because of an error in the SQL, I've added an error check to my answer so you can see what is going wrong.

Comment: You already have a table called images `LEFT JOIN images` so you have image field from that table

Comment: Here are the fields I have images has:  image_id, user_id, album_id, timestamp, and ext.  They are all int except for ext which get the files extension. and the image_id is the primary key.  In the albums table I have: album_id, user_id, timestamp, name, description(frist 50 char.) name and description are varchar. album_id is primary key.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It does thanks Aaron. Can you tell me how you derive the filename from the image table?

Comment: OK I see you are right this is the error now:                       Invalid query: Unknown column 'images.filename' in 'field list'

Comment: Ummm I don't get a filename from the table???? I just use the table to reference what image goes into what album then they are stored in a file.

Comment: How do you match an image in the table to the file?

Comment: Ok I put filename in the table now I get no errors but an empty image symbol.  How do i get the image path inserted into the filename field?

Comment: Add the path to the `src="` part of the output. E.g.: `<img src="/images/', $album['image'] ,'" />`

Comment: Im sorry Im new to php and mysql I cant seem to get it to work for me.

Comment: But I did edit my question so you can see how I retrieve the images.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer - can you also add an example of an image path (how you display an image when viewing the album)? And how each image relates to it's entry in the DB?

Comment: I updated the question again so you can see how I view the images on my page.

Comment: looks like you've got `get_images` again, can you post the code that actually displays the images?

Comment: No worries, thanks for the update. I've updated my answer to build the image filename using `CONCAT` in the SQL and the display loop to use the correct path.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhh man you have no idea how much of a pain this was,  I still don't understand it yet but I am going to go over you code to understand it better, I knew it seemed like it should be simple I just couldnt fathom the concept around it,  but thank you sooooooo much man wish I could give you two accepted answers for this, it works perfectly, thanx again for being patient with a noob, matter of fact Im so geeked up Im about to noob toob some people on MW3, thanx again bro!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!